# cant update db on ajax submit php form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can't update my database table on form submit with ajax. I don't know the reason or why this is happening. I posted my code below. Thanks.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$ime = !empty($_POST['ime']) ? stripslashes(trim($_POST['ime'])) : '';
$email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? stripslashes(trim($_POST['email'])) : '';
$poruka = !empty($_POST['poruka']) ? stripslashes(trim($_POST['poruka'])) : '';

$ime = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ime']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$poruka = htmlspecialchars($_POST['poruka']);


//Validate Phone
      if (empty($_POST["ime"])) {
          http_response_code(400);
        echo "Molimo, unesite Vaše ime i prezime.";
          exit;
      }else { 
       if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',$ime)) {
           http_response_code(400);
         echo "Dozvoljena su samo slova i space.";
           exit;
        }
      }

      //Validate Email
      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
          http_response_code(400);
        echo "Molimo, unesite Vaš e-mejl.";
          exit;
      } else {
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            http_response_code(400);
          echo "Nepravilan e-mejl format";
            exit;
        }
      }
      if (empty($_POST["poruka"])) {
          http_response_code(400);
        echo "Molimo, unesite Vašu poruku.";
          exit;
      }


    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['ime']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['poruka'])){


    $link =  new mysqli("localhost", "admin", "", "proba");
    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO message(ime, email, poruka) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $ime, $email, $poruka);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $link->close();


    $email_message .= "Ime i prezime: ".htmlspecialchars($ime)."\n";
    $email_message .= "E-mejl: ".htmlspecialchars($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Poruka: ".htmlspecialchars($poruka)."\n";

    $to = "somemail@mail.com";
    $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    if (mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers)) { 
        http_response_code(200);
       echo "Poruka je uspešno poslata!";
        exit;
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Message is not successfully sent";
        exit;
    }} else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Html

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Kontakt</h1>
    <div id="form-messages"></div>

    <form action="mail.php" method="POST" id="form">
        <input id="ime" type="text" name="ime" value="<?php echo !empty($ime) ? $ime : ''; ?>" placeholder="Ime i Prezime">

        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo !empty($email) ? $email : ''; ?>" maxlength="20" placeholder="E-mejl">

        <textarea name="poruka" id="poruka" placeholder="Poruka" maxlength="700" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo !empty($poruka)?$poruka:''; ?></textarea>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Pošalji Poštu">
    </form>
</div>
```

and JQuery

```
$(function() {
  // Get the form.
  var form = $('#form');

  // Get the messages div.
  var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

  // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
  $(form).submit(function(event) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mail.php',
        data: formData
      })
      .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#ime').val('');
        $('#email').val('');
        $('#poruka').val('');
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
          $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
          $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

If anybody has a solution, please do tell. I copied and pasted this amount of code for you to see the context. I don't know where to look for the solution. Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You mention update but you're doing an insert.

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlspecialchars()` twice, once when you set `$ime`, and again when you put `$ime` into the email?

Comment: You're also using `mail()` twice. Won't fix your code, but there's no reason for it.

Comment: You shouldn't call `htmlspecialchars()` the first time, only use it when you're displaying something in an HTML page.

Comment: Since you set `form` to `$("#form")`, there's no need to keep putting `form` inside `$()`.

Comment: You need to add error checking on `$link->prepare()` and `$stmt->execute()`.

Comment: hi guys thanks for response... I get no errors... this work without ajax...

Comment: no errors... this work without ajax...

Comment: If ajax is the difference, then have you checked to see whether ajax is submitting the data you expected? Look in your browser's developer tools, go to the Network tab and look inside the request to mail.php. Was the request as you expected? Was the response as you expected?

Comment: @ADyson Yes ,I check it... the mail is sent to my gmail,but there is no inserting in database....

Comment: I doubt this is related to ajax actually. Your code is written in such a way that the email can send even if the validation has failed. Surely the code to send the email should be within the `if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['ime'])...` statement? Also most of your validation code is missing the `exit;`, so it's possible to find a path through the validation without the program ending. This will mean that the email sends, but the DB code likely does not run. You should `exit;` if at least one of the validation tests fails, but you aren't doing this.

Comment: @ADyson  I did that last night,and still wont insert data... I can change php if you need to see it...

Comment: I edited php code,to what I have now in my mail.php.... I didnt added exit; to mail function response,I dont know if that matters

Comment: It will still send the email if `isset($_POST['submit'])` is false. You still need to move the email sending code within that if block. And yes you should put `exit` after the mail function when it fails, because otherwise your 400 response will just get overwritten with the 403 one at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I added exit to all validation in php ,and still nothing,just tried it

Comment: well it won't directly solve the problem, it's just a logical error that's all. What about doing what I said with the `if` statement. You need to do that, really to make it totally logical.

Comment: Ok I adde what you said, and i get this message  **else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
        exit;
    }** I also updated php above... On network shows me params for ime ,mail and poruka,the values I typed,and 403 error

Comment: " shows me params for ime ,mail and poruka"...what about for "submit"? There should be a value for that, too.

Comment: nothing for 'submit', it does not even show it in form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this does not work via ajax (but does via a conventional postback) is that jQuery's `.serialize()` method does *not* serialise button values.

Therefore despite you having `name="submit"` on your button, its value will not be sent to the server in the request when you make the ajax call. In a conventional postback, it would be, if the button was used as the means to submit the form.

The documentation says:

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No
>   submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
>   using a button.

Although your button click may have triggered the code which submitted the form, it is no longer doing the form submission directly (instead ajax is doing it). In theory this could be triggered by anything, and jQuery has no way of knowing it was the button which started the process.

See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ for more detail.

This causes you a problem because you test for the presence of this "submit" value before you make your database call and send your email. It's not really necessary to do this, since you're validating all the other input fields. I think you can just remove `isset($_POST['submit'])` from your `if` statement and you will have no problems. Therefore you'll be left with:

```
if(!empty($_POST['ime']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['poruka'])) {
```

Comment: It works,thanks!!!! I hope I did not take a lot of your time... I was thinking in that way,and i wanted to ask if i can somehow add submit to formData along with ime ,email and poruka... eg var ime = $('#ime').val(); etc and then in ajax formData ={ime:ime,submit:submit}... but now it does not matter... I will try it latter... Again ,thanks a lot